# Does my UML Deployment Diagram look correct?

Tags: deployment, uml

I modelled a Deployment Diagram to describe the following situation:

PC: User calls website on a webserver unsing his Browser

Intern Server: a Server that contains the IIS Web Server, the websites that are dynamically created using the Django Framework, a MySQL database where the data that is displayed in the website is stored and two scripts that interact with the Database und a website of another server.

Extern Server: unknown architecture, but contains the .html files that are being requested by the scripts on the intern server.

I am using the demo version of Visual Paradigm, sorry for the watermarks.

[image: my UML Deployment Diagram]

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @ThomasKilian  Is there any chance you could have a look / check at my deployment diagram i created for my website to see if its correct ?

Comment: @charly usually those questions are off-topic. However, just place a question and see what happens :-)

Comment: @ThomasKilian thank you for your response, that is why i did not want to post one on here as they will down vote, and  mark it as off topic.  however , i have put my question on stack exchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/389986/deployment-diagram-for-website-project      please take a look ant advice.